# Responsive Images Resizing Images

Tags: images, responsive

WordPress's automatic responsive image code is setting the size of certain images larger than it should be. Here is an example:

- On this page: http://healthyhints.wpengine.com/hot-yoga-benefits/, the image of the man lifting a weight is only 557px wide (see native image: http://healthyhints.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/leanmuscle.jpg).
- The responsive code though is causing it to stretch to 840px wide when the browser is more than 1200px wide:
  [image: Responsive Image code]

How can I change the responsive image code being generated from WordPress to change, so the image can never be set to a size larger than it's default size? All images are different dimensions, so I won't be able to hard-code a width into the code.

Any help or direction to resources would be much appreciated.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I also wondered about it this week. A page I found: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/ Hopefully someone can help us out.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem using the default themes. Might it be something related to yours? In any case, you can have a look at [`max_srcset_image_width`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/max_srcset_image_width/). In the comments there is a solution that might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help @LuisSanz. I looked into both of these options. They still seem to require hard-coding a width, which won't really work since it needs to be more dynamic.

Comment: @Andrew, the idea is to set some logic in the filter. You can access the images `$size_array` to compare each on an individual basis. I would help you gladly if I were able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LuisSanz, okay, I think I figured out the issue. I posted the answer below.

Comment: @Andrew, glad you got it working and thanks for sharing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was with some conflicting code I had in my functions file (see below). I usually use this code to remove width/height attributes from being hard-coded into the  element in the content area. Removing these somehow appears to mess up the new responsive image implementation in WordPress though. As soon as I removed this code, the responsive images appear to be working as expected.

**Conflicting Code**

```
// Remove Width & Height Attributes from Inserted Images
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );

function remove_width_attribute( $html ) {
   $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
   return $html;
}
```